# Mail is not getting delivered to bunch of mail ids while using delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, delayed-job

Iam using delay job for mailing, when iam trying to deliver the mail for a particular mail id its getting delivered but it does not working for bunch of mail ids, i have used state machine when a section's enrollment status got completed i have to send the mail

section.rb

```
after_transition :on => :complete, :do => :academic_enrolment_completion_mail

def academic_enrolment_completion_mail
 Delayed::Job.enqueue( EnrolmentsUpdateJob.new(self.id),5 )
end
```

EnrolmentsUpdateJob.rb

```
class EnrolmentsUpdateJob < Struct.new(:section_id, :academic)
def perform
Mailers.delay.academic_enrolments_completed_notification(:id)
end
```

Mailers.rb

```
mail(:to => array_user_emails, :subject => "Student non academic enrollments completed" )
```

it works well when i call it without using delayedjob and from some other controller, then why not in delayed job? and also works when i replaced array_user_emails with a single mail id. why is it so?

Comment: You put delayed job in delayed job. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Oh yes, if this is the case mail should n't be delivered if i use specific mail id right?? any how i changed it to Mailers.academic_enrolments_completed_notification.deliver but still not getting delivered

Comment: You either call `delay` on your object, along with the method to perform, or you `enqueue` an object that responds to `perform`.  You are doing *both*.  Pick one.

Comment: sorry will you please explain it little more clear?

Comment: Try taking the `delay` out of `Mailers.delay.academic_enrolments_completed_notification(:id)`